# Try-catch-finally with 'using' in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, beginner, sql, error-handling, ado.net

I want to check if I'm correctly disposing of resources using Ado.NET. I'm not sure when the 'using' statement makes .Dispose() irrelevant.

Please bear in mind I'm aware I shouldn't hardcode my SQL commands, this is just for training purposes.

```
  internal void CreateTable(string connectionString)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    tableCmd.CommandText =
                        @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coding (
                        Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                        Date TEXT, 
                        Duration TEXT
                        )";

                    try
                    {
                        int rowCount = tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Dispose();
                        tableCmd.Dispose();
                    }

                }

                // Console.WriteLine($"\n\nDatabase created! \n\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need the finally for the dispose the using will take care of that for you.  From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement   The using statement ensures that Dispose (or DisposeAsync) is called even if an exception occurs within the using block. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose (or DisposeAsync) in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

Comment: Don't use ADO.NET, use Dapper: https://dapper-tutorial.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` block or the `using` expression (collectively know as [`using` statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)) are just syntactical sugar. They will be translated to a proper `try`-`finally` block. If you visit [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) and copy-paste there the following code:

```
using System;
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        using (var disposable = new Disposable()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside the using block");
        }
    }
}

public class Disposable : IDisposable 
{
  public void Dispose() 
  {
  }
}
```

then the decompile code will look like this:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        Disposable disposable = new Disposable();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside the using block");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)disposable).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I have omitted the attributes.

---

The good news is that the compiler is smart enough to incorporate `catch` blocks into the generated code (instead of naively have two nested `try` blocks).

Source

```
using System;
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        using var disposable = new Disposable();        
        try 
        {
            _ = disposable.Get();
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
        }
        
    }
}

public class Disposable : IDisposable 
{
  public int Get() 
  {
      throw new DivideByZeroException();
  }
  public void Dispose() 
  {
  }
}
```

Decompiled

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        Disposable disposable = new Disposable();
        try
        {
            disposable.Get();
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)disposable).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public int Get()
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```